How to automatically scroll down to the bottom of a div
I have a chat application in Angular and I'm trying to scroll down all the way to the bottom like most chat apps do. I tried the native element.scrollTop property but it did not work for me.
search.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
/* ... */

@Component({ /* ... */ })
export class SearchComponent {
  selectedMessages: any[] = [];

  @ViewChild('inboxChat', { static: true })
  inboxChat?: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

  constructor(private socketService: SearchService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() { 
    if (this.inboxChat?.nativeElement) {
      this.inboxChat.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.inboxChat.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.inboxChat?.nativeElement) {
      this.inboxChat.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.inboxChat.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
    }
  }
}

search.component.html
<div class="mesgs" *ngIf="selectedMessages !== []">
  <div #inboxChat class="msg_history">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</div>

search.component.css
/* ... */
.msg_history {
  height: 516px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

The .msgs class doesn't have overflow-y at all, and I tried with that class selected as well.

I think the *ngIf condition is not causing the view child to be initialized properly.
Change it to use [hidden] so that the view child is initialized and the logic triggers the scroll to bottom.
<div  class="mesgs" [hidden]="!selectedMessages.length">
  <div #inboxChat class="msg_history">
    @for(item of  selectedMessages; track $index) {
      <div>{{item}}</div>
    }
  </div>
</div>

Full Code:
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div  class="mesgs" [hidden]="!selectedMessages.length">
      <div #inboxChat class="msg_history">
        @for(item of  selectedMessages; track $index) {
          <div>{{item}}</div>
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  selectedMessages: any[] = new Array(10000).fill(0).map((_, i: any) => i);
  @ViewChild('inboxChat', { static: true })
  inboxChat?: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Accessing the DOM element directly
    console.log(this.inboxChat?.nativeElement);
    // Modifying the DOM element
    if (this.inboxChat?.nativeElement)
      this.inboxChat.nativeElement.scrollTop =
        this.inboxChat?.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
